# how can i connect between two select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

hi i have a select tag  and i need if i click on any option from my first select.=====>i will get his attribute for it  in the second select
my example is

```
<select  name="select" >
<?php
$a={java,c++,php,python}
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)                                     
echo'<option value="'($i+1).'">'.$a[$i].' </option>';                                           
}?>                                         
</select>
<select  name="select2" >
<?php
$after={{'j','jj','jjj'},
            {'c','cc','ccc'},
                {'p','pp','ppp'},
                    {'y','yy','yyy'}};


for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)                                     
echo'<option value="'($i+1).'">'.$after[here the value of first select][$i].' </option>';                                           
}?>                                         
</select>
```

for example now if i chose java i need the select2 j jj jjj 
if i chose c++ from the first select i need in the select 2 c cc ccc 
i think it can be happen in jquerybut i don't know how it can be

Comment: You won't be doing this in PHP. Client-Side JQuery is the way to go.

Comment: yes i know that and i wrote it must be in JQuery  but i need the way how can to do this  in JQuery

Comment: Started a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xc4rs09m/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, a possible output would be:

```
<select name="selectCode" >
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">java</option>
    <option value="2">c++</option>
    <option value="3">php</option>
    <option value="4">python</option>
</select>
<br />
<select  name="select2" style="display: none;">
</select>
```

The JQuery you want is:

```
var after = {};
after[1] = {0:"j",1:"jj",2:"jjj"};
after[2] = {0:'c',1:'cc',2:'ccc'};
after[3] = {0:'p',1:'pp',2:'ppp'};
after[4] = {0:'y',1:'yy',2:'yyy'};

$(function(){
    $("select[name='selectCode']").on("change", function(){
        console.log("selectCode Changed: " + $(this).val());
        $("select[name='select2']").html("");
        for(var i = 0; i<3; i++){
            $("select[name='select2']").append("<option value='" + (i+1) + "'>" + after[$(this).val()][i] + "</option>").show();
        }
    });
});
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xc4rs09m/